# Convert Local Storage values into an XML document

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a set of strings saved on my Local Storage, is there any way, using Javascript, to parse those simple strings into xml?

Answer (score 1):

there is no native api to convert javascript object to xml, but you can try 3rd party libraries. such as:

- [x2js](https://github.com/abdolence/x2js)
- [object 2 xml](https://github.com/wankdanker/node-object-to-xml#readme)